# generate a new column based on values of previous row in a different column and current row of the same column, with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file a part of which looks something like this:

```
Date,Open,High
2018-08-29,1624.0,1628.8
2018-08-28,1658.85,1669.55
2018-08-27,1649.0,1655.45
```

What I intend to do is to create a new column by subtracting the 3rd column **High** from the previous row's 2nd column **Open**, basically **1669.55 - 1624.0** and so on throughout the file.

such that the final output will look like:

```
Date,Open,High,gener
2018-08-29,1624.0,1628.8
2018-08-28,1658.85,1669.55,75.55
2018-08-27,1649.0,1655.45,-3.4
```

What I have tried is not very smart, its like:

```
lines=$(cat test.csv|wc-l)
lines=$((lines-2))

for i in $(seq $lines);do
l=$((i+2))
sed -n "$lp" test.csv|awk -F, '{print $2 $3}' >> /dump/files.test
#and then using values from this saved file to make changes within this for loop, using tail etc.
```

which is very slow, I am not very good with awk. I attempted to look at manual and every question relevant but couldn't find anything specific doing something like this.

I also looked at [this question that is quite similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283283/subtract-previous-line-based-on-another-column) but I couldn't get it to work. I attempted reading about using [arrays](http://porthos.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/docs/gawk/gawk_9.html) in awk but that also wasn't very successful in my particular case.

A simple awk solution I will really appreciate along with a basic explanation.

Comment: You say you want to `subtracting the 3rd column High from the previous row's 2nd column Open` but then your code does the opposite - subtracts the previous $2 from the current $3. Which do you really want?

Comment: @Ed Morton forgive me it is, Infact subtracting previous $2 from current &$3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $0, (NR>1 ? $3-p : "gener"); p=$2}' file
Date,Open,High,gener
2018-08-29,1624.0,1628.8,1628.8
2018-08-28,1658.85,1669.55,45.55
2018-08-27,1649.0,1655.45,-3.4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It looks great.

Comment: It's part of the ternary expression `NR>1 ? $3-p : "gener"` that causes `gener` to be printed for the first line and the result of `$3-p` for every other line. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: It's basically doing the same thing as (@PesaThe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105599/1745001) but it's a bit more concise and should run significantly faster since it's only testing 1 condition per input line instead of 3 plus it's just printing the new value after the current record instead of creating a new field in every record which will cause awk to re-compile the whole of every record changing every FS to an OFS (even though they are the same string).

Comment: indeed, initially i compared on a smaller dataset like 4 lines something and on a larger dataset this is significantly faster.